# Check if Millis timestamp is >= 1 Hour old?

Tags: php

I have a Millis Timestamp which to confirm is a 13 digit bigint. I am unsure how to check if this is 1 hour old.

before i was using:

```
time() with strtotime('-1 hour'); I dont think this will work now.
```

This is now:

```
$timestamp = round(microtime(true) * 1000) << returns Current Timestamp.

if($timestamp >= 1 hour ago):
    do something
else:
    do something
endif;
```

i currently use:

```
if($timestamp >= strtotime('-1 hour')) {
    echo '<button class="btn btn-sm btn-warning btn-refresh" disabled=disabled name="refresh-history">Updated!</button>';
} else {
    echo '<form action="/actions.php" method="post"><input type="hidden" name="id" value='.$order_id.'><button class="btn btn-sm btn-warning btn-refresh" name="refresh-history">Update Now!</button></form>';
}
```

but the above is not working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try using this:here `$timeStamp` is your timestamp value.if your `$timestamp` is in `microtime` then compare with `strtotime('-1 hours')*1000`.

```
if ($timeStamp <= strtotime('-1 hours')) {
    echo "one or more hour old";
} else {
    echo "not";
}
```

Comment: @Elevant then you can use `strtotime('-1 hours') * 1000` to compare

Comment: @Elevant sorry i didn't get you.